# Angular 4 Ignore HTML Display of Empty Fields

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="twelve wide column">
  <div class="value">
    MaxPower: {{ powerPlant.maxPower }} MinPower: {{ powerPlant.minPower }}
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    PowerPlantType: {{ powerPlant.powerPlantType }} Organization: {{ powerPlant.powerPlantName }}
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    RampPowerRate: {{ powerPlant.rampPowerRate }} RampRateInSeconds: {{ powerPlant.rampRateInSeconds }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The powerPlant.rampPowerRate and powerPlant.rampRateInSeconds are optional fields in the associated model which is as below:

```
export interface PowerPlant {
  powerPlantId: number;
  powerPlantName: string;
  minPower: number;
  maxPower: number;
  powerPlantType: string;
  rampRateInSeconds?: number;
  rampPowerRate?: number;
}
```

How can check for this when I display? I would effectively want to completely omit the div depending on if the value is present or not! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check using *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="powerPlant.maxPower && powerPlant.powerPlantType && powerPlant.rampPowerRate" class="twelve wide column">
  <div class="value">
    MaxPower: {{ powerPlant.maxPower }} MinPower: {{ powerPlant.minPower }}
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    PowerPlantType: {{ powerPlant.powerPlantType }} Organization: {{ powerPlant.powerPlantName }}
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    RampPowerRate: {{ powerPlant.rampPowerRate }} RampRateInSeconds: {{ powerPlant.rampRateInSeconds }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the hint!